# How can I view StackExchange spoiler text with an iPad?

Tags: discussion

On the [Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site we often use **spoiler text** like this:

> spoiler text example

Normally this can only be viewed via a **mouse over**.

How can this be viewed via an iPad?

Note: I've seen this on an iPad2.

Comment: That's strange: On my iPhone, it says, "Click to show spoiler." I'd tell you what happens when I tap it, but I wouldn't want to ruin the surprise.

Comment: @joelseph, what happens on your iPad? If it works OK on your iPhone, maybe it is a bug?

Comment: @Wikis who's to say he has an iPad?

Comment: I don't have an iPad, unfortunately, but I find it surprising that it would work differently between the two devices. Hopefully someone else with an iPad can try it and chime in. At least we know that it _should_ be touch-device-friendly.

Comment: iPad 1 user here, and it seems to only work when I'm not signed in, because of the mouseover events for the “did you find this useful” prompt at the bottom of questions and answers.

Comment: On my iPad, it defaults to the desktop site. My iPhone defaults to the mobile site. The mobile site works fine because there's no mouse over. But the desktop app requires a mouse over. iPad lack a mouse, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see spoilers on touchscreen?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-to-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen)

Comment: Not an iPad owner, but on my Touchpad, tapping the spoiler area displays the spoiler.

Comment: @Keen, does not work on iPad2.

Answer (score 5):

This was "[fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen)" by making it possible to view spoiler text in the (very ugly on a decent sized screen) "mobile" (meaning small, not "easily moved") version of SE.

IMO this isn't fixed at all.  [There is a post to have it properly fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site).  Unfortunately, this has been **declined**.  The official StackExchange position is that they don't care about this problem and you should go use some other view for StackExchange if you want this to work.  As far as they are concerned (according to the answer on the post from a SE employee) touch-based devices aren't enough of SE's traffic to care about, and if you want to be able to read spoiler text on a touch-based device (whether iPad or Windows 8 or Kindle Fire or anything else) you should go find some other way to view the site.

Extremely disappointing, but there's nothing we can do about this.

Comment: More than 2 years later, the traffic is still too low from touch devices?

Answer (score 2):

You should ask at [Ask Different Meta](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com) to get someone to edit Stack Exchange's javascript to make spoilers react to the touchstart and touchend/touchcancel events in addition to the normal mouseover and mouseout events.